# How to enable the drag and drop feature on the node in GetOrgChart library

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, getorgchart

**How to enable the drag and drop feature on the node in GetOrgChart plugin?**

I have used the free version of GetOrgChart plugin to draw Organization chart. I have a requirement to drag and drop the node present in the OrgChart. What I have to do is to drag a node from the chart and drop it to another node to assign it to that particular node. I haven't got any help and suggestions from the documentation of the GetOrgChart.

Any help is appreciated.

http://www.getorgchart.com/

Comment: Did you solved your query?